# timer for closing a program in cmd

Tags: batch-file, cmd, timer

I want to make a bat file that starts a program(actually another bat) and close the program after a certain amount of time.

my program is like this.

-In 'Program_A.bat'

```
@echo off
set /p sec="Enter the amount of sec you want to run : "

start Program_B.bat

timeout /t %sec%

tasakkill /F /IM cmd.exe
```

I found It works well when I put little amount of time. like 10 seconds.
But When I put 3600 or more, It doesn't kill the Program_B.bat properly.

And I if I put 172800 secs in order to set 48 hours, it doesn't work.

How can I manage these problems?

Comment: The reason why it doesn't work for 172800 seconds is because the [`timeout` command](https://ss64.com/nt/timeout.html) has a limit of 100000 seconds. That command alone is not appropriate for that task. You can put it inside some kind of loop though or try some other alternatives ([this link](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/wait.php) can maybe help but doesn't really talk about pros, cons or limits of each method).

Comment: Also I would like to make you aware of the fact that killing another process isn't that easy in batch. First of all it could be that the process you're trying to kill is not the only one with `cmd.exe` as name. If this is really the case you'll need another way to find the correct process to kill. Secondly depending on what `Program_B.bat` actually does you may want to use the `/T` option of the [`taskkill` command](https://ss64.com/nt/taskkill.html) to kill the child processes along with the process you want to kill (first be sure you have the right process though)

Comment: Also the name of the executable used to gracefully terminate (without `/F`) or really kill (with `/F`) is `taskkill` being with full path and file name `%SystemRoot%\System32\taskkill.exe` and not `tasakkill` as you wrote in your batch file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

killing just `cmd.exe` may kill windows, that you don't want to kill.
You can give your application a unique title and kill it by that title.
Also to work around the 100000 seconds limit of timeout, just timeout one hour in a loop:

```
start  "UniqueTitle" Program_B.bat
for /l %%a in (1,1,48) do timeout 3600 >nul
taskkill /fi "windowtitle eq UniqueTitle"
```

Comment: Thank you! Your code works perfectly!
Have a nice day!

Comment: The console fakes its initial client as the owner of the window (instead of conhost.exe), which is cmd in this case. So a taskkill that targets this cmd process works by sending a `WM_CLOSE` message to the console window, which in turns broadcasts a `CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT` to all processes attached to the console. Each has 5 seconds to exit gracefully before being forcibly killed. A program can register a control routine that handles this event (i.e. returns `TRUE`) and initiates a graceful shutdown. cmd's `Handler` routine simply chains to the default handler that calls `ExitProcess`.

Comment: If the initial console process exits or gets killed, the console promotes the next process in its list as the owner. Other processes attached to the console generally don't own a window. For processes that don't own a window, taskkill requires the `/F` option to forcibly terminate them.

Comment: @Yong-WookHA - If this works well, please select it as the answer. Select the check mark.

Answer (score 0):

Run a bat_A file that runs your program_B and after timeout 99999 run bat_B that waits another 72801 seconds then kill the task.
Or maybe timeout /t 99999 and below line(command) timeout /t 72801 if it works in the same bat_A.

thanks